# ssh via paramiko load .bashrc

Tags: python, bash, paramiko

I want to automate the same action which I do via ssh (putty).
After connecting using putty, my `.bashrc` is loaded (so I can use aliases). If I try to do this in Python, alias `sanity` is invisible:

```
sanity: command not found
```

Using `source .bashrc` wasn't solution.

```
 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('xxxxxxx', username='x',   password='x',  key_filename=None, look_for_keys=False)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(
    """
    sanity;
    """)

    stdout.flush()
    for line in stdout:
        print line
    print "END"

    print stderr.read()
    ssh.close()
```

Comment: Please share your console output (on  using sanity)(where sanity app ?)

Comment: It's much more complicated, we have to work on linux with complicate aliases (no written by us), there fore analyse aliases and run it "manually"  is no good idea, I need to run this ssh the same as I have terminal on machine.

Answer (score 7):

because you are running a command over ssh you are not running a login shell and so `.bashrc` is not sourced.

see the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/306530/run-remote-ssh-command-with-full-login-shell

Edit:

try setting `get_pty=True` when calling [exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)

otherwise try forcing a login shell

```
exec_command('bash -l -c "sanity;"')
```

Comment: More impotent then reason is solution :), could tell me how should I do it in python same like do it putty?

Comment: solution is in the link I provided

Comment: which one? - I suggested 2. if neither then how about the other solutions suggested in the superuser.com link ?

Answer (score 2):

From `bash` man page:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt

So if you want using aliases you must set the `expand_aliases` option first.

Comment: Could you tell me how should I do this?

Comment: @BartłomiejBartnicki - please! just google : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Answer (score 1):

The other submitted solutions did not work for me. I had to both force an interactive shell and use get_pty together. The following code is working and tested with Ubuntu:

```py
source_bashrc = True # switch this flag to revert to 'normal' execution
command_to_execute = 'll'

if source_bashrc:
   command_to_execute = f'bash -ic "{command_to_execute}"'

client.exec_command(command_to_execute, get_pty=source_bashrc)
```

The -i flag creates an interactive terminal, which sources bashrc.
I got the hint from [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/use-bash-aliases-ssh-based-session/).